# Relation between number of coefficients and number of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Is there a nice way to solve the following problem?

Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer for which there exist distinct integers $a,b,c,d,e$ such that $(x−a)(x−b)(x−c)(x−d)(x−e)$ has exactly $k$ nonzero coefficients. Find, with proof, a set of integers for which this minimum $k$ is achieved.

The solution I have seen is to find an example assuming $k = 3$ and then prove that $k \neq 1,2$. But this seems like you would only be able to do it this way if you know beforehand the answer was $3$. Even if one proved $k \neq 1,2$ first, how would I know $k = 3$ is possible without trying a least a few choices and having to expand those five terms in the product? This is training for a math contest, so time is of the essence, what could I employ to quickly find this solution? Is guessing and checking really the best way to solve this?

Comment: Lots of contest math problems have the following structure: find "obvious reasons" why the answer has to be at least $X$; then trust that $X$ really is the right answer and try to find a proof. Here, Descartes' rule of signs is the "obvious reason" why the minimal number of coefficients is $3$, and so we can postulate that $3$ really is the minimum and go about trying to prove it by finding an example.

Comment: Here's what I've deduced. By shifting by $e$, we can WLOG look at $x(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$, then note that if $(x-a)(x-b)$ and $(x-c)(x-d)$ both expand to a difference of perfect squares then we have exactly three coefficients in the expansion. This shows that there is a solution with $x=0$ as a root, and that an easy set of solutions is $\{0, a, b=-a, c, d=-c\}$ then just pick $a \neq c$.

Comment: You are expected to make the observation that if you only have two non-zero coefficients, like in $x^5+A x^k, k<5$, then the possible zeros of that polynomial are $x=0$ and the integers $x$ such that $x^{5-k}+A=0$. Is it possible for $x^{5-k}+A=0$ to hold for four distinct integers $x$? In other words, even though some *educated* guessing may be involved, you also need to be able to eliminate some alternatives. Solving a well designed contest problem is never a single track process.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah thats not too hard. My question was more along the lines of, "why, once i've deduced $k \neq 1,2$ that I can suppose it is $3$ and work off that assumption?" This seems unsafe since in a contest it could cost a lot of time. But according to Greg Martin, since it is easy to show that it is not $1$ or $2$, it is fine more often than not to guess that $k=3$ and work with that.

Comment: Well. That's the next possibility. Either you succeed in finding the polynomial when $k=3$, or, while failing to do that get the idea why you may need to try $k=4$ instead. I don't see any waste of time here. You see, that's what I did with $k=2$ above. I tried it, failed, and it became obvious why it must fail.